# Our SQL Server stored procedure "dies" - but how can I find the cause?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We have a *SQL Server* Stored Procedure which does a very long, painful `INSERT INTO.. SELECT FROM...` command.

It then writes a status message, via a second stored procedure, to say if it was successful or not.

```
BEGIN TRY

    EXEC [Add_To_Log_Table] 'Starting the INSERT command...'

    INSERT INTO [Very_Large_Table]
    SELECT /* About 30 fields */
    FROM /* Lots of tables */ 

    EXEC [Add_To_Log_Table] 'The INSERT was successful.'

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    EXEC [Add_To_Log_Table] 'The INSERT failed, ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

When our data set is small, this all works beautifully.  The `[Very_Large_Table]` gets populated, and our `'The INSERT was successful.'` message gets written to our log table.

But sometimes, when we are dealing with very large data sets, the '`Starting the INSERT command...`' message gets written to our log file, Activity Monitor shows that the `INSERT` *is* running, but after several minutes, the Stored Procedure just "dies".

The `CATCH` command simply doesn't kick in, so we have no way to detect or recover from this situation.  Is there a way to find out what was the cause ?

I know that *SQL Server Management Studio* does have some logs (Management \ SQL Server Logs) but these don't show any errors occurring.

I was wondering if SQL Server somehow stores statuses/most recent error messages in one of its internal tables ?

We're running SQL Server 2008 R2, on Windows Server 2008 R2, there's plenty of free hard disc space on the drives used by our database, and the database recovery mode is set to SIMPLE.

Comment: Never heard of the term `sp dying` but anyway when you think it has died have you have checked for any dead locks? I mean sps just dont die. Any process you start in sql server (Sp execution in this case) can have three possible states in the SQL Server , `Running` , `Runable` or `Suspended`. When you think the SP has died , run `sp_who2` in a separate window and see what is going on with your sp's process , you just need to find out why it is taking so long to execute, is it a resource bottle neck or is it just the amount of data it is handling, a bit more investigation is required :)

Comment: what do you meant by dies? Idle

Comment: Also since this is a data upload process and you maybe dealing with a large amount of data at a time, I would suggest using the proper tool for it something like `SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services)` .

Comment: By "dies", I mean, it runs the INSERT statement (I can see this in Activity Monitor), but it neither runs any of the commands following it or throws an exception which our CATCH can handle. It just stops running. For me, it also seems like a memory issue, but thought, surely, SQL Server will make some log of this problem somewhere (?)

Comment: Ah ok, well unfortunately SQL Server will not log any thing that you may use later to diagnose the issue, unless you are running a SQL Trace, having said that you can run the procedure yourself and see yourself where it is going wrong by using `sp_whoisActive (writter by Adam Machanic)` or simple use `sp_who2` to check any blocking or progress of the processes on sql server

Comment: Cartesian join in the `SELECT` perhaps? Missing part of a join? Hard to tell without seeing the code, or knowing the database.

Comment: Yup, I know.  I deliberately didn't include the tables, joins, etc...  The table we're inserting into *does* have partitions, it's inserting from 7 other tables, but really that's not the point.  My question is really, "when something *terminal* occurs in an INSERT command, does SQL Server log the cause/error message somewhere ?"

Comment: There are at least [some cases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx#Anchor_4) where `try ... catch` can't catch the errors. I would assume those would appear in the SQL Server log, but maybe there's something that could cause it?

Answer (score 2):

> but after several minutes, the Stored Procedure just "dies".
>
> The CATCH command simply doesn't kick in, so we have no way to detect
> or recover from this situation. Is there a way to find out what was
> the cause ?

If a command timeout occurs while the proc is being executed, the client API sends an attention to cancel the executing query. The CATCH block will not be executed in this case, but the timeout exception should be raised in the application code. Make sure the application is properly handling and logging these exceptions.

You could create a trace (Extended Events or SQL Trace) to capture attention events if you don't have access to the app code.

Comment: Good comment, thanks.  You're right, this stored procedure is being called by a background thread from an ASP.Net application, but, it has a timeout of 5-hours.  With large datasets, the SP will have died within 1 hour, so I don't believe it's a timeout issue.  I personally believe this is a memory issue, SQL Server's being asked to pull together too much data at once, but my question is, when such a fatal problem occurs, does SQL Server log this problem somewhere ?

Comment: @MikeGledhill, I would expect an error to be raised that can at least be logged by the client.  I've never seen a proc "dying" without raising an error.  You might try adding `THROW` or `RAISERROR` to the `CATCH` block but I would have expected an error writing to the log table to raise an error too.

Answer (score 1):

This part looks suspicious..

> when we are dealing with very large data sets, the 'Starting the INSERT command...' message gets written to our log file, Activity Monitor shows that the INSERT is running, but after several minutes, the Stored Procedure just "dies".

This can be due to `select` part taking a lot of time or `insert` is an overhead due to many indexes or many many factors..

My way of troubleshooting this problem would be below

1.run query again
2.Open  a new query windows and run below command,

```
select status,blocking_session_id,wait_type,last_Wait_type
from
sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id=<<your query sessionid>>
```

The above query helps you in identyfing where is bottle neck..

Say for example,i ran below query..which inserts data into database and wait type shows me WRITELOG,which means if i commit 100 once,rather one at a time,i can help reduce this wait type..

```
create table test
(
id int identity(1,1) primary key
)

while 1=1
begin
insert into sometable
default values
end
```

Not all the times, you could see your session running,some times you will not see it in EXEC_REQUESTS DMV,I that case,you can use below

```
select * from sys.processes
```

You may get different Wait type,say like IO..in that case,you will have to troubleshoot based on that and try to add good indexes,so that your select will run faster ,it can also be a memory issue,since ,if you are low memory,sql will swap data back and forth and even a good query will suffer

so in summary ,know what the wait type is and troubleshoot based on that

Comment: Good idea.  When I run "select * from sys.sysprocesses", it shows that that process used a huge amount of CPU and Physical IO, and is now "suspended".

Comment: whats the wait type

Answer (score 1):

Most of the comments assume this process is really running and just needs to be debugged.  I have personally experienced a couple instances where it did indeed just "die".  Nothing in the error log.  No return code.  Debug messages would come out right up to the stored procedure call and then nothing and it would be over.

But if you called the stored procedure independently it would work fine.  The phenomena would only occur in a more complex situation where a stored procedure called a trigger which called another stored procedure which called another one.

In one case modifying the length of the procedure handled the issue - the actual physical length of it.  In trying things out it would die at a later point if I took some code out earlier.

I stumbled on this thread because I'm running into that scenario now and still need to find the reason or the workaround. I'll post when I find it for this instance.